# Combine template and `ConfigParser`

Tags: python, templates

I have a template file called `foo.cfg`:

```
[Box]
box.active={box_activate}
resolution_tracker.active=true
box.api_key={box_api_key}
box.api_secret={box_api_secret}
box.job_interval=480
box.max_attempts=6
box.users={cs_user}

[Google]
google.active={google_active}
google.job_interval=480
google.users={cs_user}
google.key_file_name={google_p12_file}
google.service_account_id={google_service_account_id}
```

and I dictionary that holds those values:

```
import ConfigParser

keys = {
    'box_activate': 'false',
    'box_api_key': '',
    'box_api_secret': '',
    'google_active': 'true',
    'google_p12_file': 'GOOGLE_P12_FILE',
    'google_service_account_id': 'GOOGLE_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_ID',
    'cs_user': 'me',
}

parser = ConfigParser.ConfigParser()
parser.read('foo.cfg')
sections = parser.sections()
for section in sections:
  options = parser.options(section)
  for option in options:
    try:
      table[option] = parser.get(section, option)
      if table[option] == -1:
        self.log.info("Skip: %s" % option)
    except:
        self.log.exception("Exception on %s!" % option)
        table[option] = None

with open('foo.properties', 'w') as configfile:
    parser.write(configfile)
```

I use `ConfigParser` to parse `foo.cfg`, and I rewrite it to a `foo.properties` file. However I want to be able to replace all the values between `{}` with the actual value in `keys`. This will I have a way to dynamically generate `properties` files. I also have a `dict` called `table` that's obtained after parsing the `foo.cfg` file. I thought about using `strings` `format`, but I believe must be an easy to do this. Any suggestions?

Comment: Use [**`StringIO`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stringio.html)

Comment: @PeterWood Could you formulate your answer a lil better?

Comment: There's nothing much else to add. Just create a `StringIO` object from the formatted string and feed it to `ConfigParser`.

Comment: Another option would be to change things a little (not so little) bit and use a [Template string](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#template-strings).

Comment: @PeterWood Could you please write an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can format the keys and use [**`StringIO`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stringio.html) to create a file-like object to pass to ConfigParser's [**`readfp`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/configparser.html#ConfigParser.RawConfigParser.readfp) method:

```
from StringIO import StringIO
# ...

with open('foo.cfg') as foo:
    fixed = foo.read().format(**keys)
parser = ConfigParser.ConfigParser()
parser.readfp(StringIO(fixed))

# ...
```