# Eliminating spaces between equal signs in ConfigParser - Python

Tags: python, templates

I got an excellent answer from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33425339/combine-template-and-configparser/33425642#33425642) post, that covered everything I wanted.

```
[Box]
box.active = false
resolution_tracker.active = true
box.api_key = 
box.api_secret = 
box.job_interval = 480
box.max_attempts = 6
box.users = 

[Google]
google.active = true
google.job_interval = 480
google.users = <useremail>
google.key_file_name = <key_file>
google.service_account_id = <account_id>
```

However, the question still lingering around is how to remove the spaces in the equal assignments. For example:

```
box.active = false
```

Must be

```
box.active=false
```

That's it, I want to remove the white spaces between the `=`. The `.properties` file is generated with `ConfigParser` in Python, but it seems those white spaces are creating problems. Of course I can use other things in order to remove those white spaces, but is there a more elegant solution using `StringIO`, `ConfigParser` or any other of the `Python` Libraries?

** Edit **
This question isn't a duplicate because we are trying to find an easier way to remove the white spaces around the `=` using the API, instead of rewriting the `ConfigParser` class.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32167217/stop-configparser-adding-spaces-to-delims-after-upgrade-from-python-2-7-3-to-2-7/32167382#32167382

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`ConfigParser.write()` has a flag for that

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import sys
from configparser import ConfigParser
from io import StringIO


CONFIG = '''
[Box]
box.active = false
resolution_tracker.active = true
box.api_key = 
box.api_secret = 
box.job_interval = 480
box.max_attempts = 6
box.users = 

[Google]
google.active = true
google.job_interval = 480
google.users = <useremail>
google.key_file_name = <key_file>
google.service_account_id = <account_id>
'''

parser = ConfigParser()
parser.readfp(StringIO(CONFIG))
parser.write(sys.stdout, space_around_delimiters=False)
```

output:

```
[Box]
box.active=false
resolution_tracker.active=true
box.api_key=
box.api_secret=
box.job_interval=480
box.max_attempts=6
box.users=

[Google]
google.active=true
google.job_interval=480
google.users=<useremail>
google.key_file_name=<key_file>
google.service_account_id=<account_id>
```

Comment: Are you sure? `parser.write(configfile, space_around_delimiters=False)`:
`TypeError: write() got an unexpected keyword argument 'space_around_delimiters'`

Comment: @philippe That's a python3 script - you need that for python2?

Comment: yes .. I was using `import ConfigParser`

Comment: @I've installed `configparser` with `pip`, and that solved the problem.